# TxnNumber vs RefNumber in ReceivePaymentQuery - QBXML

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

What is the difference between TxnNumber and RefNumber when I query receive payments?

And how can I get payment date? I'm seeing three TxnDate field in ReceivePaymentRet.

```
...
<ReceivePaymentRet> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
    ...
    <TxnNumber >INTTYPE</TxnNumber> <!-- optional -->
    ...
    <TxnDate >DATETYPE</TxnDate> <!-- payment date? -->
    ...
    <RefNumber >INTTYPE</RefNumber> <!-- optional -->
    ...
    <AppliedToTxnRet> 
        <TxnDate >DATETYPE</TxnDate> <!-- payment date? -->

        <LinkedTxn> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
            <TxnDate >DATETYPE</TxnDate> <!-- payment date? -->
        </LinkedTxn>
    </AppliedToTxnRet> 
    ...
</ReceivePaymentRet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details:

- `TxnNumber` - this is QuickBooks' internal transaction #, not really useful for anything that you do
- `TxnDate` - this is the date entered into the QuickBooks UI on the payment (generally the date the payment was received)
- `RefNumber` - this is the reference # entered into the QuickBooks UI on the payment (usually a check # for checks, and a transaction ID for credit card transactions)
- `AppliedToTxnRet/TxnDate` - this is the date of the *invoice* that the payment was applied to
- `AppliedToTxnRet/LinkedTxn` - this is an array of other related transactions linked to the payment (e.g. they might be credit memos, etc.)
- `AppliedToTxnRet/LinkedTxn/TxnDate` - this is the date entered into the QuickBooks UI of those related transactions linked to the payment

> What is the difference between TxnNumber and RefNumber when I query
>   receive payments?

`RefNumber` is the one you want - it's the one that shows up in the UI.

> And how can I get payment date?

The base-level `TxnDate` is the payment date you want.